# Book with comprehensive description of (history and operation of) Harvard university

Tags: university, books, reference-request, policy, academic-history

I really am not sure if my question falls under this Stack Exchange forum, but I am going to try.

A friend of mine asked me if there is a book with some sort of comprehensive description of Harvard university. For example a book covering the history of the university, the schools and departments, fraternities/sororities, services available to the students, as well as potentially other useful general-purpose information regarding the operation of Harvard university. Personally, I have never been to Harvard (or MIT), so I have next to zero knowledge about answering the question immediately.

One educated guess was to try to figure out if there is a relevant book by Arcadia Publishing. However, searching for [harvard university](https://www.arcadiapublishing.com/Search?searchtext=harvard%20university&searchmode=anyword&searchoption=allbooks) did not return very relevant results.

Another idea for searching for a relevant book, was through the bookstore that is usually found on big universities. For instance, UVA bookstore has an entire collection with [books about UVA](http://uvabookstores.com/shop_product_list_tradebooks.asp?catalog_name=Qk9PS1MgJiBDQUxFTkRBUlMgQUJPVVQgVVZB&catalog_id=1903). Of course I believe that this can not be the norm in general, but Harvard has a longer history than UVA so I would expect for someone to be able to find a few general purpose books regarding the history, the structure, and the relationship of the university with its students (with elements from modern time as well). Unfortunately, I am not entirely sure which bookstore is the official one for Harvard university - assuming that there is one.

Finally, from what I understand, there is also scattered information available in electronic brochures that is created by schools or departments and is potentially related to admissions for new students. However, there is no such information gathered in a printed book - at least nothing that I could find. Perhaps you know something related for a specific school, e.g. Engineering and Applied Sciences, Arts, etc?

Are there any people out there who have graduated from Harvard and can potentially point me to the right direction? In which bookstores would you search around Harvard so that you can potentially find a book (or books, where different books specialize on different aspects of what I am looking for) with this kind of information? Can you also provide me with some online references?

Comment: You are aware of the [Handbook for Students](http://handbook.fas.harvard.edu/book/welcome)?  Pretty much every university has something like this (it might be part of the university catalog), but these days they are mostly distributed online, and in some cases are never printed on paper, since there will be changes from year to year.

Comment: Thank you very much @NateEldredge . This is a good suggestion that I momentarily forgot to check! Indeed, there is lots of useful information along the lines that I am looking for. And you are also right that this kind of book is usually not printed on paper as there are changes from year to year. Nevertheless, it is a valuable resource in the direction that I am looking for.